# Saving user ID with Entity Framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework-6, userid

I'm using entity framework v6.2.0 and ASP Net MVC to create a web page to access a database and edit the entries. The overwhelming majority of the code is the basic framework provided for me. The database is connected successfully and entries can be viewed, edited, and deleted. Additionally I have implemented some rudimentary paging, searching, and sorting as instructions are provided by microsoft on how to implement those. The last thing I need to do before the site is truly functional is to pull the userID from the users login and save that as the EnteredBy field before saving any changes or new entries to the table.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            yasukosKitchen.EnteredBy = currentUserId;
            db.YasukosKitchens.Add(yasukosKitchen);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

This code seems very simple, and I added `using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;` so it compiles fine. However when I attempt to test this code the EnteredBy field is left blank or null.

My search for information turned up a post suggesting the use of the following line of code.

```
ApplicationUser currentUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == currentUserId);
```

However when I attempt to add that I get an error, the ApplicationUser cannot be found and Users does not exist in this context. The fix for this is probably staring me in the face but my lack of experience and comprehension is killing me.

As suggested: My question is, how do I get and/or correctly add the UserId to my database entry?

Comment: Hi Ryan, your question is well-formed to a large extent, but I would add a final clear question ("My question is: How do I achieve ...?").

Comment: Done, Thank you sir.

Comment: Check if there is a reference to Users table in DbContext Class

Answer (score 2):

If your Database Context has an entry to your YasukosKitchen table; usually something like this,

```
public virtual DbSet<YasukosKitchen> YasukosKitchens {get; set;}
```

and YasukosKitchen table has a column 'EnteredBy' (string 128 length), then you can post the value for the logged in user's Id straight from the View.
Add this to the very beginning of the Create view.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
```

At the end of the form just before the submit button, add this code.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EnteredBy, new { @Value = User.Identity.GetUserId() })
```

I'm not sure what is the functionality of 'Users' table.